# Mongoose - Customize skip and limit for the first time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am kind of stuck in a situation . I really want a simple query. I want to count all the result coming from find query and then I want to apply skip and limit but not for the first time. In simple, I want all the items and their count first. Based on that I want to apply skip and limit , over the results. How can I achieve this I am stuck. I tried different things, like storing the first query result in a variable and the applying the `find() limit() skip()` but it did not work.

**sample**
This is what I have done so far .

```
Product.find({
        'category.category_name': request
    },
    function (err, searchedResults) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send("There was a problem getting the category based record .");

        } else {
            //Assign searched results length as product Count
            productCount = searchedResults.length;

            // apply ceiling - to make total pages
            totalPages = Math.ceil(productCount / pageOptions.limit);

            // tell the pagination what is the kind of pagination
            kindOfPagination = 'searchProduct';

            // call pagination func
            pagination(productCount, totalPages, pageOptions.page, pageOptions.limit, kindOfPagination);

            res.status(200).json({
                'products': searchedResults,
                '_meta': _meta
            });
        }
    })
```

Now I need to apply the `skip` and `limit` part. Like this

**skip and limit**

```
 Product.find().skip(pageOptions.page * pageOptions.limit)
    .limit(parseInt(pageOptions.limit))
    .exec('find', function (err, products) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                'products': products, // consuming the product variable
                '_meta': _meta
            });
        }
    });
```

Now in `skip` and `limit` i want the results returned from the sample to be applied. How can I do this ? I tried this before.

**what I have tried**

```
    Product.find({
            'category.category_name': request
        }).skip(req.query.page * 10)
        .limit(parseInt(10))
        .exec('find', function (err, searchedResults) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send("There was a problem getting the category based record .");

            } else {
                pageOptionsFunc(req.query.page);

                //Assign searched results length as product Count
                productCount = searchedResults.length;

                // apply ceiling - to make total pages
                totalPages = Math.ceil(productCount / pageOptions.limit);

                // tell the pagination what is the kind of pagination
                kindOfPagination = 'searchProduct';

                // call pagination func
                pagination(productCount, totalPages, pageOptions.page, pageOptions.limit, kindOfPagination);

// I am storing the results in a searchResultsSample
 searchResultsSample  = searchedResults;

                res.status(200).json({
                    'products': searchedResults,
                    '_meta': _meta
                });
            }
        })
```

See searchResultsSample. Now I used it `skip` and `limit` part. Like this

```
searchResultsSample.find().skip(pageOptions.page * pageOptions.limit)
    .limit(parseInt(pageOptions.limit))
    .exec('find', function (err, products) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                'products': products, // consuming the product variable
                '_meta': _meta
            });
        }
    });
```

But it did not work and I got an error function not defined. How can I do this ?

Comment: Not exactly a new concept. The "skip" is always `n-1` multiplied by page size for the page that you are on. So page `1` becomes `.skip((1 - 1) * 25 )` or `0` and with a page size of `25` page `2` becomes `skip((2 - 1) * 25)` or simply `25`, and so on. So you always want "both" in the code. It's just that the value `1-1` becomes `0` for the very first page.

Comment: okaye @neil but what about the limit dude ? how can i forget about the limit for the first time ?

Comment: @neil can you pleas check the answer is this the right way ?

Comment: You always limit. There is no possible case in "paging" that you don't ask for for a limit, otherwise there is simply. This is an age old process that never never changes.

Answer (score 1):

First count and then apply skip and limit.

```
router.get('/products', function (req, res) {

    let items_perpage = req.query.itemsperpage || 5;
    let page = req.query.page || 1;

    let skip = items_perpage * (page - 1);
    let limit = parseInt(items_perpage);

    Product.find({'category.category_name': request}).count(function (err, totalCount) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(err.stack);
            return res.status(500).send({ success: false, msg: 'Internal Server Error' })
        }
        else {
            Product.find({
                'category.category_name': request
            }).skip(skip).limit(limit).exec(function (err, searchedResults) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err.stack);
                    return res.status(500).send({ success: false, msg: 'Internal Server Error' })
                }
                else {
                    let total = {}
                    total.count = totalCount;
                    if (total.count % items_perpage == 0) {
                        total.pages = (total.count / items_perpage);
                    }
                    else {
                        total.pages = (parseInt(total.count / items_perpage) + 1);
                    }
                    return res.status(200).send({ success: true, msg: 'All Products', total: total, data: searchedResults });
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: the second find in else, is it being applied on the results ?

Comment: yes, First I count the product as per your search data, second, i apply skip and limit on data and return the result.

Comment: let me try it brother.